# Problems generating a DOCX document from a template with phpWord and then converting it with LibreOffice to PDF on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, libreoffice, phpword

I have [template.docx](/questions/tagged/template.docx) template with mark ${table} inside. I create [document.docx](/questions/tagged/document.docx) using phpWord and need to convert it to PDF using LibreOffice on Ubuntu. Here is my code

v1 filling table

```
        $doc_table = new Table();
        if(count($table_data)>0) {
            foreach ($table_data as $k1 => $row) {
                $doc_table->addRow();
                foreach ($row as $k2 => $col) {
                    $doc_table->addCell()->addText($col);
                };
            };
        };

        $word_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template.docx');
        $word_template->setComplexBlock('table', $doc_table);
        $word_template->saveAs('document.docx');
```

v2 filling table

```
        $doc_table_xml = ''.
            '<w:tbl>'.
                '<w:tblPr>'.
                    '<w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>'.
                    '<w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>'.
                    '<w:tblBorders>'.
                        '<w:top w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>'.
                        '<w:left w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>'.
                        '<w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>'.
                        '<w:right w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>'.
                        '<w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>'.
                        '<w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>'.
                    '</w:tblBorders>'.
                    '<w:tblLook w:val="04A0"/>'.
                '</w:tblPr>'.
                '<w:tblGrid>'.
                    str_repeat('<w:gridCol/>',count($table_data['0'])).
                '</w:tblGrid>'
            ;
        if(count($table_data)>0) {
            // Fill table with rows and sells
            foreach ($table_data as $k1 => $row) {
                // Add row
                $trow_xml = '<w:tr>';
                foreach ($row as $k2 => $col) {
                    $trow_xml.= '<w:tc><w:tcPr/>'.'<w:p><w:t>'.$col.'</w:t></w:p></w:tc>';
                }
                $doc_table_xml.= $trow_xml.'</w:tr>';
            }
        }
        $doc_table_xml.= '</w:tbl>' ;
        $word_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template.docx');
        $word_template->setValue($key, $doc_table_xml);
        $word_template->saveAs('document.docx');
```

Convert to PDF

```
   $command = 'libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export document.docx --outdir doc_print';
   $output = shell_exec($command);
```

When use v1 filling table there are no PDF file at all but DOCX file can open in MSWord
If I start the same command from shell I receive "Error: source file could not be loaded"

When use v2 filling table there are no PDF file at all but DOCX file can open in MSWord
If I start the same command from shell I receive PDF file as result but without table in it

Comment: Try to use [absolute paths](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-path-absolute-relative) in your command line. This might help to locate the files.

Comment: You can take a look on alternative solution, you can consider using [Carbone](https://carbone.io/).